# How to create temporary component React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I want to set an animation for each element created by clicking the background, of the website homepage (a ripple effect like raindrops falling on water), and disappear moments after. So far the solution I found was to unmount each component by setting a state to false, inside this child component. I have the feeling I'm using a really bad practice and I want to correct it.

Home ->

```
export interface Coordenates {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
const Home: React.FC = () => {
    const [mousePositionArray, setMoussePositionArray] = useState<Coordenates[]>([])

    const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {

        setMoussePositionArray(
            mousePositionArray
                ? prev => [...prev, { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY }]
                : [{ x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY }]
        )
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={handleClick} style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh', position: 'relative' }} >
            {mousePositionArray.map((position, i) => (
                <Ripple key={i} positionX={`${position.x}px`} positionY={`${position.y}px`} />
            ))}
        </div>
    )

};
```

Ripple component ->

```
interface Props {
    positionX: string;
    positionY: string;
}
const Ripple: React.FC<Props> = ({ positionX, positionY }) => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(true);

    // Simulate callback on animation completion
    useEffect(() = {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setActive(false)
        }, 2000)
    }, []);

    if (!active) return null;

    return (
        <SVG positionX={positionX} positionY={positionY} >
            <g className="blob" >
                <path className="blob-path" d="M138.4, -233.9C176.8, -217.5, 203.6, -175.3, 225.7, -132C247.9, -88.7, 265.5, -44.3, 259.5, -3.3999999999999995C253.6, 37.5, 224.2, 75, 200.5, 115.6C176.7, 156.1, 158.6, 199.7, 126.1, 222.8C93.7, 245.9, 46.8, 248.5, 1.7999999999999998, 245.3C-43.2, 242.1, -86.3, 233.2, -127.3, 215C-168.3, 196.9, -207.1, 169.4, -227.1, 132.1C-247, 94.7, -248, 47.3, -249, -0.5999999999999996C-250, -48.5, -251, -97, -229.6, -131.8C-208.2, -166.6, -164.3, -187.6, -122.3, -201.9C-80.3, -216.1, -40.2, -223.6, 4.9, -232.1C50, -240.6, 100, -250.2, 138.4, -233.9 " fill="none" stroke="#F7770F" strokeWidth='6'>
                </path>
            </g>
        </SVG>
    )
};
```

[Image: Rendered components stacking up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YExRA.png)

[GIF: Rendered components stacking up](https://gfycat.com/fondpoliticalindigowingedparrot)

[Intended result here](https://gfycat.com/insignificantthatindochinahogdeer)

Appreciate all the suggestions.

Comment: I don't think you are doing it wrong. There are 2 options anyways: 1) return null (what you are doing OR 2) have the state in the 'parent' and simply not render (return) the `<Ripple />`
And put `[]` dependency in the useEffect. In your case it doesn't change a thing (only renders 2 times anyways) but it's bad practive: you might get in an infinite loop.

Comment: Added the dependency array, thanks :) Still, doing the way I'm doing, I'm getting stacks of components rendered after unmounting like It's shown in the pictured I linked in my question. Seems wrong...

Comment: Ok. Yet, you are returning null. There's no HTML. But you can go for the 2nd option then.

Comment: So for that, I'll have to have a setState in the child props, so at the end of the animation, the child tells the parent when he can stop rendering it?

Answer (score 0):

Use React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.querySelector(''));

Comment: Can you elaborate more your answer, please?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).